# Spring Boot Hikari & Refresh Endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp

Using spring 2.0.2.RELEASE and hikari 2.7.6 and finchley.rc2. 
Still getting `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The configuration of the pool is sealed once started. Use HikariConfigMXBean for runtime changes`. error on refresh endpoint.

I cant move to hikari 2.7.4(although it solves my problem, but i am tracking the usage of pool resources like current , idle, pending connections and such values are coming NaN. So how to do it with hikari 2.7.6?

Is there a way to exclude hikari from refersh? or something like that?

FYI : I have created my custom datasource for mysql(read / write split)

```
datasource.write.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://172.16.1.122:3306/db?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
datasource.write.username=root
datasource.write.password=root
datasource.write.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
datasource.write.platform=mysql
datasource.write.continue-on-error=true
datasource.write.testOnBorrow=true
datasource.write.connection-test-query=SELECT 1
datasource.write.maximum-pool-size=1

datasource.read.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://172.16.2.122:3306/db?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
datasource.read.username=root
datasource.read.password=root
datasource.read.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
datasource.read.platform=mysql
datasource.read.continue-on-error=true
datasource.read.testOnBorrow=true
datasource.read.connection-test-query=SELECT 1
datasource.read.maximum-pool-size=20
```

This is my DB properties

```
@Bean(name = "writeDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.write")
    public DataSource writeDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "readDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.read")
    @Primary
    public DataSource readDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

@Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfb = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emfb.setDataSource(dataSource);
        emfb.setPackagesToScan("com.abc");        
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        emfb.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);

        /** Setting additional properties */
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        props.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        props.put("hibernate.ejb.interceptor", hibernateInterceptor());
        props.put("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings","false");
        emfb.setJpaProperties(props);

        return emfb;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using Finchley.RC2? It’s not the latest stable release and you will probably find that bug is fixed if you upgrade.